# Firebase: sort alphabetically a nested field in last children

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this Firebase database with the following data:

[image]

Here is a part of the JSON file:

```
"SWPL6X" : {
  "-LznFoTKvdc5318O97h_" : {
    "direction" : "in",
    "excluded" : false,
    "in" : 422,
    "multiplier_out" : 1.05,
    "name" : "MaM.OUT.90F8",
    "out" : 6582,
    "total" : -6160
  },
  "-M2ZQU2azNc-JTKKXojU" : {
    "direction" : "in",
    "excluded" : false,
    "in" : 316,
    "multiplier_out" : 1.05,
    "name" : "CdG.Out.96A4",
    "out" : 2509,
    "total" : -2193
  },
  "-M3zVSWzqb4TaezY1Kua" : {
    "direction" : "in",
    "excluded" : false,
    "in" : 4806,
    "name" : "MaM.in.3FBC",
    "out" : 748,
    "total" : 4058
  },
```

I just need to order alphabetically the last children by the field "name" (String) but I can't find a way to achieve it.

The code before I tried to sort is the following:

```
getSensors: function(uid, event_id, success){
  var ref=firebase.database().ref('clients_events_sensors/'+ uid+ '/'+ event_id);
  kap.firebase.bindings.liveObject(ref, success, function(e){
    kap.log('cant get client event sensors', e)
  });
},
```

I tried changing the first line to this with no effect:

```
var ref=firebase.database().ref('clients_events_sensors/'+ uid+ '/'+ event_id).orderByChild('name');
```

This function is only called once here, the logs retrieved keep the same order as the one coming initially from Firebase:

```
app.data.getSensors(kap.page.uid, kap.page.event_id, function(sensors) {
    $.each(sensors, function(k, sensor){
      //remove picture to avoid blowing localstorage memory
      sensor.photo=null;
      //Replace total by in+out/2 in the app only
      sensor.total = Math.round((sensor.in+sensor.out) / 2);
      sensor.sum = sensor.in+sensor.out;
    });
    kap.log('got sensors', sensors);
    kap.page.sensors = sensors;
    kap.page.fill();
  });
```

The log:

> got sensors {
> "-LznFoTKvdc5318O97h_":{"direction":"in","excluded":false,"in":492,"multiplier_out":1.05,"name":"MaM.OUT.90F8","out":6983,"total":3738,"photo":null,"sum":7475},
> "-M2ZQU2azNc-JTKKXojU":{"direction":"in","excluded":false,"in":339,"multiplier_out":1.05,"name":"CdG.Out.96A4","out":2686,"total":1513,"photo":null,"sum":3025},
> "-M3zVSWzqb4TaezY1Kua":{"direction":"in","excluded":false,"in":5150,"name":"MaM.in.3FBC","out":836,"total":2993,"photo":null,"sum":5986},
> "-M9Y7Ed7JtPSKTUQXRhd":{"direction":"in","excluded":false,"in":470,"multiplier_out":1.05,"name":"Volt.Out.99CE","out":2323,"total":1397,"photo":null,"sum":2793},
> "-MAa2FZ5z5fMejpSL7zp":{"direction":"in","excluded":false,"in":4615,"multiplier_in":1,"name":"CdG.In_A011","out":486,"total":2551,"photo":null,"sum":5101},
> "-MAa2QX5rvjWlT_2z7YQ":{"direction":"in","excluded":false,"in":3729,"name":"Volt.In_A013","out":1203,"total":2466,"photo":null,"sum":4932},
> "-MAa2UaqVDyxQrQojFiR":{"direction":"in","excluded":false,"in":400,"multiplier_out":1.05,"name":"Pagnol.Out_A014","out":2205,"total":1303,"photo":null,"sum":2605},
> "-MBiKvKAAWQkU8RABWR0":{"direction":"in","excluded":false,"in":2613,"name":"Pagnol.In_A015","out":987,"total":1800,"photo":null,"sum":3600}}

Am I missing something?

Comment: What's the value under `name` in your JSON? It might help if you show the JSON as text, instead of as a screenshot. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added the part of the JSON file, thank you

Comment: That looks fine at first glance to me. Can you show how you're processing the data? Or at the very least log it, in a way that I can use to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your effort @FrankvanPuffelen, I added the code where the function is called, along with the log produced. The order remains the same. I am actually taking over this project, so I might not be aware of something in the code..

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what `kap.firebase.bindings.liveObject()` does and how it them passes the data to `getSensors`. Is there a way to reproduce the problem with just the Firebase JavaScript API?